# Rails: How to manage a "static" time-value attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

What is the best way with Rails to have a “time” attribute (selected by the user) which is supposed to always be displayed as the same “static” time value?

(Meaning: It should always show the same time, for example “14:00”, *completely independently of any user’s time zone and/or DST value*.)

Until now, I have tried the following setup:

- In the MySQL database, I use a field of the type `time` (i.e. with the format: `14:00:00`)
- In the Rails view, I use the helper `time_select` (because it’s really handy)

However, it seams that with this approach, Rails’ ActiveRecord will treat this time value as a full-blown Ruby Time object, and therefor convert the value (14:00:00) to the default time zone (usually set to ‘UTC’) for storage and then convert it back to the user’s time zone, for the view. And if I’m not mistaken, this also means that the fluctuating DST value will make the displayed time value fluctuate throughout the year (and the same happens if the user moves to another time zone).

So what is the best way to manage a simple “static” time attribute with Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any time related functionality, why not save it as an string field. Since from your question description its evident that functionalities such as timezone doesn't effect your use case, so just make it a normal `VARCHAR(8)` and save the value as a string and parse it such as `Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` before saving it to the database, you can also write this logic inside your `ActiveRecrd` model class

```
def static_time=(value)
  super(value.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
end
```

you can somewhere in the code say `model_object.static_time=Time.now` and this will automatically parse it, if you want to get the time as a ruby object retaining the format you can simply do it defining a custom getter.

```
def static_time
  current_time = Time.now
  time_keys = [:hour, :min, :sec]
  current_time.change(**Hash[time_keys.zip(super.split(":"))])
end
```

Comment: Thank you - the only thing I seem to need to correct is your getter, since `Time.now.hour=` is not a valid setter. So the method would need to be something like: `Time.new(Time.now.year, nil, nil, super.split(":")[0], super.split(":")[1], super.split(":")[2])`

Comment: @TomDogg Ah thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer to what I think is a more better way.